# Can I $addToSet and upsert an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, upsert

I'm using Mongoose and my Schema looks like:

```
var WalletSchema = new Schema({
  accounts: [String]
});
```

My query (Node.js) looks like:

```
Wallet.update {accounts: account}, {$addToSet: {accounts: account}}, {upsert: true}, (err, updWallet) ->
  asyncCb err
```

However, I don't have any `wallets` in my database and I expected this to upsert. It does not. Instead it returns an error: `MongoError: Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It might be related to that [open issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3946), where you try to $addToSet on a field which is used in the query. Try the `$all` workaround: your query should be `{accounts: { $all: [account] }}` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have to initialize your account document with an empty accounts array on first creation or use `$push` if your first `$addToSet` fails. `$push` creates a new field if the field is absent, which `$addToSet` does not.

Comment: This may have changed in a recent MongoDB version, but they have this in their docs now: "If the field is absent in the document to update, $addToSet creates the array field with the specified value as its element."

Comment: Mongodb recently upgraded the addToSet behavior. upsert is now supported by default: 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Answer (score 6):

This Behavior is now supported by Mongodb 3.2

From MongoDB documentation:
**If the field is absent in the document to update, $addToSet creates the array field with the specified value as its element.**

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: Copy of the comment above which is one year older.